# Ggplot2 fill by one condition, but shade by another

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am having trouble with ggplot2. I am trying to plot this boxplot that has several boxes for every x-axis value. Each set of boxplots is divided into two sets, features, and resolutions, with every feature set having boxes for every resolution. My issue is that I want to color(and fill) by feature set, but have different shades of that color for every resolution. I have only been able to color by feature and fill by resolution so far, and this is my code:

```
df %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=partition, y=value, fill=resolution,color=feature_set)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black','blue3','darkred')) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color=feature_set,fill=resolution),lwd=0.7) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1") +
  theme(
    legend.position="right",
    plot.title = element_text(size=11)
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_text(data = df,aes(y=1.1,label=max_clusters,color=feature_set),size = 2.5, 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.85),check_overlap = TRUE) +
  xlab('label') +
  ylab('label') +
  ggtitle("title") + 
  ylim(0,1.1)
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You could try setting an `alpha` aesthetic to get different shades of a fill. You could also plot a white version first to avoid grid lines etc showing through if you don't want them to.

Comment: Besides the use of the `alpha` aes as suggested by Andrew, if you want different shades then create a color palette for all combos of resolution and feature_set. Then map e.g. `interaction(resolution, feature_set)` on fill and/or color.

Comment: Thank you both! I hadn't thought of using alpha, cheers